# IEEE 754 floating point math

Tags: javascript, ieee-754

What is the risk of precision loss associated with maths like the following when using IEEE754 floating point numbers (in JavaScript)?

```
10*.1
```

i.e. integers multiplied by a rational number.

Comment: I didn't vote, but it is not clear to me what form you're expecting the answer to take.

Comment: [Some disasters caused by numerical errors](http://ta.twi.tudelft.nl/users/vuik/wi211/disasters.html).

Comment: @NPE Can the risk of precision loss be quantified? For example: "It is OK unless the result falls out of the exactly representable range of integers within IEEE754."

Comment: AFAIK the statement in your comment is true ("It is OK unless the result falls out of the exactly representable [set] of [real numbers] within IEEE754."), but does that really help to answer the question? I am not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:** The question was edited to add "that is a divisor of" long after this answer was posted, see below the fold for an update.

---

> What is the risk of precision loss...

It's **virtually guaranteed**, depending on the integer and floating point number involved, because of the mismatch between what we use (fractional numbers in base 10) and what IEEE-754 floating point numbers actually are (fractional numbers in base 2, then represented in base 10 for our use). Just as we can't represent `10 / 3` precisely in base 10, there are various base 10 numbers that cannot be precisely stored in base 2.

But to your specific question: It breaks at 3: `3 * 0.1` is `0.30000000000000004`.

You don't even need multiplication for it, though, addition is more than sufficient, the classic example being `0.1 + 0.2`, which also results in `0.30000000000000004`.

Examples (JavaScript numbers are IEEE-754 double-precision floating point):

```js
snippet.log(0.1 + 0.2); // 0.30000000000000004
snippet.log(3 * 0.1);   // Also 0.30000000000000004
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

---

Re your addition of "that is a divisor of": I take it you mean where the fractional number relates to the original integer such that the result will be an integer with actual math.

No, that's not safe either. :-) Because fractional values that would, in real math in base 10, result in an integer may not be precisely represented in IEEE-754's base 10, and so inaccuracies creep in. `0.00000000002`, for example, demonstrates this problem:

```js
snippet.log(200000000000 * 0.00000000002); // 3.9999999999999996
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

I don't know whether there's a larger value that would introduce the imprecision, but it wouldn't surprise me.

Comment: This does not answer the question. The question is regarding precision loss if the result should be an integer, which you have not addressed at all.

Comment: @TJCrowder - and if the result is an integer, can we say anything further about the chance of precision loss?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: The "...that is a divisor of..." part was added later, long after I answered the question. Prior to that, there was no indication other than the example that the result would also be expected to be an integer (if indeed that's what "that is a divisor of" is meant to mean).

Comment: Oh I see. Sorry about that.

Comment: I amended the question, then subsequently removed the amendment, because TJCrowder answered so fast. The "...that is a divisor of..." was an accidental remnant of my modification (now removed).

Comment: @Ben: I've updated the answer to address it, though. :-)