# Javascript decimal number comparison

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have two decimal numbers which only slightly differ at the last two decimal places
 eg. num1 = 1.12345 and num2 = 1.1234567
but doing a num1 === num2 check fails. 
What would be the best way in javascript to make the comparison return true if there are only few extra decimal places in num2 compared to num1?

I know that num2 could be rounded by few decimal problems but therein arises the problem because I don't know in advance how many decimal places would be truncated in num1.

Comment: you need to use toFixed

Comment: According to your logic, `1.23456 === 1.234567`, but `1.23456 !== 1.234559`?

Comment: `00` and `67` differ "slightly"? You will need to define exactly what you want to happen before you can implement it.

Comment: Why do you need the comparison? Where is this being used?

Comment: its not 00 and 67 its .0000000 and .0000067, thats pretty slight lol

Comment: doesn't matter if .000000000000000000001 or .9999999999

Comment: i am sure there is a better solution, therefor i type it here: you can parse those numbers like strings and compare them afterwards

Comment: Thats what `Number.EPSILON` is good for

Comment: Often the best way to compare floating point numbers is to check if x minus y is less than some negligible difference _epsilon_ such as `Math.abs(x - y) < THRESHOLD` ... that may or may not be `Number.EPSILON`, and it depends on your specific purpose. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/207577/3767

Comment: @StephenP thanks! I had an opinion that this should be done only when the nos. have had some kind of computation on them. eg 0.1+0.2 === 0.3 fails because 0.1+0.2 evaluates to something like 0.30000000000000004. But if its known that the numbers that are coming from outside will always differ only in the last few places (because one of them gets rounded off by a few decimal places), then do you think a direct comparison would be ok? or should it still be done using Number.EPSILON?

Comment: @JKnowles - again, it depends on your purpose. Early in my career I worked in banking; (I don't remember the exact number but) If two money amounts differed by 1/1000 of a cent they were considered equal, so our epsilon was 0.001 which is _much_ bigger than `Number.EPSILON`, but `Number.EPSILON` is a good number to correct for inaccuracy in IEEE-754 floating point math. [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27623286/17300) has some good info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition of `===` is not what `===` means, but I think I get what you are trying to do.

First, figure out which number is the shortest. 
Then, only compare the numbers by the amount of decimals in the shorter number.

I'm sure there is a cleaner way to do this, but I've drawn it out step-by-step to show the progression and to help make sense of the process.

```js
function compare(x, y){
  // Convert both numbers to strings:
  var str1 = x.toString();
  var str2 = y.toString();

  // Get the shortest string
  var shortest = str1.length >= str2.length ? str2 : str1;
  console.log("Shorter number is: " + shortest); // Just for testing

  // Get number of decimals in shorter string
  var dec = shortest.indexOf(".");
  var numDecimals = shortest.length - dec - 1;

  // Only compare up to the least amount of decimals
  console.log(x + " and " + y + " equal? " + (str1.substr(0, numDecimals + dec + 1) === str2.substr(0, numDecimals + dec + 1)));
}

compare(1.12345, 1.1234567);
compare(1.22345, 1.1234567);
compare(-101.22345, -101.1234567);
compare(-101.12345, -101.1234567);
```

Comment: thanks Scott, couldn't have explained it better! Accepting as answer :-) was thinking of doing the same way but wasn't sure if there were some built-ins in javascript! 
Also minor modification could be to have `str1.substr(0, numDecimals + dec) `
instead of `numDecimals+2` because the characteristic (part to the left of the decimal) could be 3-4 digits or even a negative no like -102.123456789

Comment: @JKnowles It would have to be `dec + 1` because `indexOf()` returns a zero based index. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 2):

There are two possible ways of doing this (that I am aware of). The first would be to use toFixed, to round your numbers. The second would be to present some precision factor, in order to define "slightly" (let's say slightly means "a difference less than 0.0001"). The functions that implement this are below

```
// a, b - the numbers you wish to compare, digits - the number of digits to round to
function compareUpTo(a, b, digits){
  a.toFixed(digits) === b.toFixed(digits) // first we round the numbers, then we compare them
}

// a, b - the numbers you wish to compare, precision- the amount to which the numbers are allowed to be different (let's say 0.01 for up to two digits)
function compareUpTo2(a, b, precision){
  Math.abs(a-b) < precision // we make the difference and check whether or not the difference is smaller than our desired precision (we use Math.abs to turn a negative difference into a positive one)
}
```

Comment: this isn't super helpful without any explanation

Comment: `1.12345.toFixed(5)` results in `"1.12345"`, while `1.1234567.toFixed(5)` results in `"1.12346"`. Your first function will return `false`, but according to OP's rules, it should return `true`.

Comment: I do not recommend ever using `compareUpTo2()`, it introduces a bias because it allows higher relative error for smaller numbers by fixing the absolute error. It is much better practice to fix precision using [units in the last place](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place) instead.

Comment: this is a great answer! but in my problem, precision is not fixed because the characteristic(part to the left of the decimal point) could have between 1 to 3 digits

Answer (score 0):

You can use toString and compare strings. This will solve the problem of not knowing in advance the number of digits.

```js
    num1 = 1.12345 ;
    num2 = 1.1234567 ;
    str1 = num1.toString();
    str2= num2.toString();
    leng1 =str1.length;
    leng2=str2.length;
    minLength = Math.min(leng1 ,leng2);//ignore extra decimals
    str1 =str1.slice(0,minLength);
    str2 =str2.slice(0,minLength);
    console.log(str1 ===str2); //true
```

Comment: @ScottMarcus I misunderstood the question so I corrected it to suit the question. I am sorry

Comment: Better. I've edited the answer so that your code runs in a Code Snippet. You should consider using Code Snippets in all answers where you provide code that can be executed. It proves to everyone that your code does what it says it does.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do this is to find the length of the "shorter" number, then truncate the "longer" number with this code from MDN:

```
function truncate(number, precision) {
    var factor = Math.pow(10, precision);
    // *shouldn't* introduce rounding errors
    return Math.floor(number * factor) / factor;
}
```

Where precision is the length of the shorter number. Which, you could get like this:

```
let num1 = 1.12345,
    num2 = 1.1234567;

// gets everything after the . as a string
let str1 = String.prototype.split.call(num1,'.')[1],
    str2 = String.prototype.split.call(num2,'.')[1];

let precision = Math.min(str1.length, str2.length);
```

Then, call the above function on both numbers and do your comparison.

```
if(truncate(num1,precision) == truncate(num2,precision) //do stuff
```

I modified the function on the [Math.round() page from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round) for this answer.