# Calculation discrepancy for 22/7

Tags: javascript, linux

I use the Linux browser (Firefox and Chrome) and Linux bc program to do calculation and get different results, can anyone explain why?

Browser output:

22/7..=3.1428571428571427937015414499910548329353332519531250000000000000
1/7..=0.1428571428571428492126926812488818541169166564941406250000000000

code: var x=parseFloat(22/7).toFixed(64);

acerI7 kflee # bc -i -l
bc 1.06.95
Copyright 1991-1994, 1997, 1998, 2000, 2004, 2006 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
For details type `warranty'.

scale=65

1/7
.14285714285714285714285714285714285714285714285714285714285714285

22/7
3.14285714285714285714285714285714285714285714285714285714285714285

Comment: `BC` has greater precision ... javascript only has about 15 or 16 digits of precision

Comment: See [*IEEE 754 floating point math*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27623217/ieee-754-floating-point-math). Do you need more precision? Do the results need to match?